# Mips , comparing a String taked in input with a stored String

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I'm writing a function that takes an input string and compares it to a stored string in this case I created a .asciiz string with the value "false" in it , and if the string taken in input is equal to "false" it will output a message "they match" and "they dont match" otherwise.

But my code doesn't work well, I can't figure out why.

```
.data


savedString:  .asciiz "false"

write: .asciiz "write the string to compare:"

match: .asciiz "they match"

nonmatch: .asciiz "they dont match"

string: .space 256



.text

main:

writeSTring:

li $v0,4
la $a0,write
syscall

la $a0, string
li $a1, 256
li $v0, 8
syscall


checkVisibility:

li $t3,0

la $a0,savedString       # adress stringsaved and writed string            
la $a1,string         


jal match

## if they match

beq $v0,$zero,match_msg

## else 

j noMatch_msg


match:

add $t0,$zero,$zero  
add $t1,$zero,$a0  
add $t2,$zero,$a1  


loop:  


lb $t3($t1)         #load a byte from each string  
lb $t4($t2)  
beqz $t3,checkt    #str1 end  
beqz $t4,nonEqual  
slt $t5,$t3,$t4     #compare two bytes  
bnez $t5,nonEqual 
addi $t1,$t1,1      #t1 points to the next byte of str1  
addi $t2,$t2,1  
j loop 

nonEqual:   

addi $v0,$zero,1  
j end

checkt:  

bnez $t4,missmatch  
add $v0,$zero,$zero  

end:  

jr $ra



match_msg:

la $a0,match_msg     
li $v0,4
syscall

j exit

noMatch_msg:

la $a0,nonmatch     
li $v0,4
syscall

j exit


exit:

li $v0,10 # exit
syscall
```

Comment: SPIM and MARS have debugging features that lets you single-step through your program, and see the contents of registers and memory as each instruction is executed. So it shouldn't be particularly difficult for you to find the problem yourself.

Comment: que te paso Michael antes eras chevere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program doesn't compile. I made some changes and added some code, and now I think that the program does what you want.

```
.data  
string: .space 20  

write:.asciiz "write the string to compare:"  
match:.asciiz "\nthey match"
nonmatch:.asciiz "\nthey dont match"  
strToCompare: .asciiz "false\n"

.text
.globl main

main:  
    li $v0,4        #loads msg1  
    la $a0,write  
    syscall

    li $v0,8
    la $a0,string
    addi $a1,$zero,20
    syscall          #got string to manipulate

    li $v0,8
    la $a0,match
    addi $a1,$zero,20

    la $a0,string             #pass address of str1  
    la $a1,strToCompare         #pass address of str2  
    jal methodComp      #call methodComp  

    beq $v0,$zero,ok    #check result  
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,nonmatch
    syscall
    j exit
ok:  
    li $v0,4  
    la $a0,match  
    syscall  
exit:  
    li $v0,10  
    syscall  

methodComp:  
    add $t0,$zero,$zero  
    add $t1,$zero,$a0  
    add $t2,$zero,$a1  

loop:  
    lb $t3($t1)         #load a byte from each string  
    lb $t4($t2)  
    beqz $t3,checkt2    #str1 end  
    beqz $t4,missmatch  
    slt $t5,$t3,$t4     #compare two bytes  
    bnez $t5,missmatch  
    addi $t1,$t1,1      #t1 points to the next byte of str1  
    addi $t2,$t2,1  
    j loop  

missmatch:   
    addi $v0,$zero,1  
    j endfunction  
checkt2:  
    bnez $t4,missmatch  
    add $v0,$zero,$zero  

endfunction:  
    jr $ra
```

Comment: I see that you added a \n at the end o "false" , I guess that was one of the reasons it didnt work?